# Rust Actix-Web HttpServer Type Definition

Tags: rust, type-inference, actix-web

I'm currently working on an actix-web application but am having some difficulty while trying to refactor some of the code into smaller functions. When setting up the HttpServer the variable type is just inferred.

`main.rs (basic example)`

```
use actix_web;

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    // prepare the server variable but don't start it
    let _server = actix_web::HttpServer::new(|| {
        actix_web::App::new().service(nothing)
    }).bind(("0.0.0.0", 31)).expect("FAIL");

    // redacted other stuff

    // ok now handle the server start
    return _server.run().await;

}

#[actix_web::get("/")]
async fn nothing() -> actix_web::HttpResponse {
    return actix_web::HttpResponse::Ok().body("nothing");
}
```

When moving it into a separate function though, I need to explicitly put the type definition so I can return it.

`main.rs (refactored example)`

```
use actix_web;

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    // prepare the server variable but don't start it
    let _server = get_server();

    // redacted other stuff

    // ok now handle the server start
    return _server.run().await;

}

#[actix_web::get("/")]
async fn nothing() -> actix_web::HttpResponse {
    return actix_web::HttpResponse::Ok().body("nothing");
}

fn get_server() -> /* unknown type definition */ {
    return actix_web::HttpServer::new(|| {
        actix_web::App::new().service(nothing)
    }).bind(("0.0.0.0", 31)).expect("FAIL");
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to handle the type definition of the actix-web HttpServer when it cannot be inferred. I guess more generally I am wondering if it is possible to return an inferred variable type from a function but more specifically I'm just having difficulty defining the HttpServer type because of how many Generics it seems to need in its definition

Comment: I found that comment that says that you could maybe use types `Resource` or `Scope` in place of `HttpServer` for the return type https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1156

Comment: I gave this a go but it doesn't seem to be happy with it, I'm just getting a mismatch type definition error `expected struct Resource, found struct HttpServer`

Comment: I remember that I gave up on this with my apps with actix, I just defined my HttpServer in the main...  I'm not sure this has a solution, or maybe something super verbose...

Comment: @Peterrabbit in a way I'm kinda glad I'm not the only one that's been banging my head against a wall with this